# Pandas compare many columns with each other and if any two are identical - true

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| Name | Flag | part1 | part2 | part3 | part4 | part5 | part6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | Y | Paper | Machinery | IT | Machinery | None | None |
| Company2 | N | IT | Business | Paper | None | None | None |
| Company3 | N | Bio | Bio | Trades | None | None | None |
| Company4 | N | Air | Communication | Oil | Oil | Oil | None |
| Company5 | Y | Business | Oil | Air | Food | None | None |
| Company6 | N | Food | Business | Paper | Bio | Air | Paper |

I need to get a new column "Result" where I compare all values in columns part1 - part6 and if text in any two columns are identical - the result is true and vice versa.
It has to be like this:

| Name | Flag | part1 | part2 | part3 | part4 | part5 | part6 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | Y | Paper | Machinery | IT | Machinery | None | None | True |
| Company2 | N | IT | Business | Paper | None | None | None | False |
| Company3 | N | Bio | Bio | Trades | None | None | None | True |
| Company4 | N | Air | Communication | Oil | Oil | Oil | None | True |
| Company5 | Y | Business | Oil | Air | Food | None | None | False |
| Company6 | N | Food | Business | Paper | Bio | Air | Paper | True |

Is there any simple way to do it?
I tried something like this:

```
df['Result'] = (df['part1']==df['part2']) | (df['part1']==df['part3']) | (df['part1']==df['part4']) | (df['part1']==df['part5']) | (df['part2']==df['part3']) | (df['part2']==df['part4']) | (df['part2']==df['part5']) |(df['part3']==df['part4']) | (df['part3']==df['part5']) | (df['part4']==df['part5'])
```

But this way is too weird and uncomfortable, I believe that it has a better solution. (In my task I have to compare 21 columns)

Comment: Which one is `part1_ind`? Or it's typo?

Comment: @Kshitiz sorry I edited it, it was a mistake:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case try

```
df['out'] = df.filter(like='part').apply(lambda x : x[x!='None'].duplicated().any(),1)
Out[24]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I tried but it shows "True" in every case :(

Comment: @AnnaShevtsova What do you mean by `True` in every case? Probably thats because you have duplicates in all rows. This code here works as expected

Comment: @Onyambu I can`t attach the image. But it is really strange cause it must work!

Answer (score 0):

This answer was written against a previous version of the question in which `part1` was compared with all other columns, rather than a search any duplicate `part#` values.

Do an index-based equality comparison, then reduce with `any` across rows (by specifying `columns`, makes sense-ish, but is less than intuitive).

```
>>> df.filter(regex=r'part[2-9]').eq(df['part1'], axis='index').any(axis='columns')
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Note that I use `filter` to quickly select the `part2` ... `part6` columns, this could be specified manually as well. You must pass `axis='index'` and `axis='columns'` (or the corresponding `int`) to both `df.eq` and `df.any` respectively to do the comparison and reduction properly.

Comment: I edited a frame for better understanding, I need to compare all columns because identical text can be in 5 and 6 columns and it will be true)

Comment: Can you clarify as to how your logic changed? There isn't any difference in outputs here.

Comment: I see your edit now, what you're doing is really looking for duplicates: BENY's answer above then would be the best way to do that. There isn't a Series-wise duplicate check attached to `DataFrame`, so you'll have to apply that duplicate check over rows. (Note also that because `None` or `np.nan` repetitions count as duplicates, you need to filter them out.)

Comment: I tried this solution but it shows "True" in every case :(